# Slow GML (Geographic Markup Language) file reading with readOGR in R

Tags: r, gis, rgdal, gml-geographic-markup-lan, r-sf

I have a lot of GML files to loop through in R, but none of them are extremely heavy (max file size is 600 Mb, but normally they range between 10-60 Mb). My problem is that readOGR function from the {rgdal} package takes too long to read them, and it slows down the loop a lot. It takes between 3 minutes up to 30 minutes to read a single file...

I have looped through .shp files and they do not take up so much time to read.

So my question is actually two:

- Is there a faster function in R to read GML files? Have not been able to find one so far
- If a faster reading function isnt possible, is there perhaps a quick way to convert the GML files to .shp?

Code to my readOGR:

```
llayer<-ogrListLayers(gmls)[1]
a<- readOGR(dsn=gmls, layer=llayer, encoding = "UTF-8", disambiguateFIDs = T)
```

Comment: You could try package `sf`. It's usually much faster, and I think it should handle gmls

Comment: @LoBu have tried, it is much faster BUT apparently my computer has an issue with GDAL data, I have tried to set the environment GDAL_DATA variable in windows manually but it does not work... I'll try on my laptop and see what happens. I have also tried assigning  the projection manually but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried today on my PC, absolutely right you were. I'll post the answer, thanks a lot! @LoBu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LoBu said in the comment section, `sf::st_read()` is much, much faster than readOGR. The only matter to keep in mind is that now you work with `sf` objects and you must either perform your operations using the `sf` package or convert the sf object to a SpatialPolygonsDataframe with `as(file, "Spatial")`.

**Warning**, for people using work laptops: errors may occur as I mention in the comment section. Make sure you are using a laptop with full admin permits